# Simple error with Database library using codeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->where('del_in !=',1);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query;
```

I am getting sql following error Please help me to solve this...

**ERROR**:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`product`) WHERE `del_in` != 1 LIMIT 0 ,

Filename: D:\wamp\www\shopcart\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Comment: Try to use `<>` as operator

Comment: Is that your full active record query i guess limit is not correctly passed

Comment: `limit` is not even shown used in your code.

Comment: try this `$this->db->where('del_in !=','1');`

Comment: I tried <> operator nothing change in error

Comment: $this->db->where('del_in !=','1'); Nothing Change in error

Comment: can you try running the raw query from your client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure column name and table name are correct. After that try this code

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('del_in !=',1); 
$this->db->from('product');    
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit please up vote if that answer was useful.